# Displaying an array of images in picturebox

Tags: c#, arrays, image, picturebox

I'm very new to visual C#
I want to display an array of images in a picture box

Here's my code:

```
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\pictures", "*.jpg");

Image[] images = new Image[5];

for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
{
    images[index] = Image.FromFile(list[index]);
}
```

When I run it, the picturebox is blank.

Comment: `PictureBox`es appear nowhere in your code - it follows that no `PictureBox`es will display the images.

Comment: Where is the PictureBox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying an array of images in picturebox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868757/displaying-an-array-of-images-in-picturebox)

Answer (score 0):

add a form-level varaible:

```
private int selectedImageIndex = -1;   // to store the active index in the images array
```

add a button with a click event handler:

```
selectedImageIndex++;  // increment the active index
// if the active index is equal to the image count we've gone past the end of the array, so loop back to the beginning.
if (images.Count == selectedImageIndex) { selectedImageIndex = 0; }
pictureBox.Image = images[selectedImageIndex];  // assign the selected image to the picturebox
```