# Displaying an array of images in picturebox?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, picturebox

I'm very new to visual C# I want to display an array of images in a picture box

Here's my code:

```
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\pictures", "*.jpg");
Image[] images = new Image[5];
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)

{
    //HERE IS WHERE IM STUCKED WITH
    picturebox[index] = Image.FromFile(list[index]);
}
```

Comment: what is picturebox! Shouldn't it be images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit-1 : This answer has a scope limited to Win-Forms C#.
You need certain assemblies added in your application before using this code.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Edit ended;

**Original Answer**

You have to draw all image to one image for displaying them in single picturebox

That is bit complex you can use mutiple pictureboxes

In following code they are created dynamically according to need:

```
    // For confirm visibility of all images set 
    this.AutoScroll = true;

    string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\pictures", "*.jpg");
    PictureBox[] picturebox= new PictureBox[list.Length];
    int y = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < picturebox.Length; index++)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(picturebox[index]);
        // Following three lines set the images(picture boxes) locations
        if(index % 3 == 0)
            y = y + 150; // 3 images per rows, first image will be at (20,150)
        picturebox[index].Location=new Point(index * 120 + 20, y);

        picturebox[index ].Size = new Size(100,120);
        picturebox[index].Image = Image.FromFile(list[index]);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting errors saying `does not contain defination for AutoScroll ,  Directory, PictureBox, Controls, Points, Size, Image`  please tell me which directive should i add.

Comment: You should be using winf-forms to use this code. Please see my edit at top

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided throws an object reference exception.  Otherwise thanks for the example!

```
for (int index = 0; index < picturebox.Length; index++)
{
     this.Controls.Add(picturebox[index]);
     // Following three lines set the images(picture boxes) locations
```

should be

```
for (int index = 0; index < picturebox.Length; index++)
{
    picturebox[index] = new PictureBox();
    this.Controls.Add(picturebox[index]);
    // Following three lines set the images(picture boxes) locations
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `picturebox[index].Image  = Image.FromFile(list[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

//this code help you to work with picturebox in arraye

```
public partial class Form_Begin : Form
    {
        PictureBox[] pictureBoxs = new PictureBox[50];
        public Form_Begin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBoxs[0] = pictureBox1;
            pictureBoxs[1] = pictureBox2;
            pictureBoxs[2] = pictureBox3;
            pictureBoxs[3] = pictureBox4;}



            List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();
 private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <2; i++)
                {
                    pictureBoxs[i].Image =your_name_project.Properties.Resources.Image_1;                     // Load Image_1 from Resources on property of picturebox  
                }
                for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    pictureBoxs[i].Image =your_name_project.Properties.Resources.Image_2;                    // Load Image_12 from Resources on property of picturebox 

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void picbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        PictureBox[] picture = new PictureBox[5];
        int x = 0;
        int y = 15;
        for (int index = length; index < picture.Length; index++)
        {
                picture[index] = new PictureBox();
                picture[index].Size = new Size(100, 50);
                open.Title = "OPen Image";
                open.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
                DialogResult result = open.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    picture[index].BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                    picture[index].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
                    listBox1.Controls.Add(picture[index]);
                    if ((x % 3 == 0) && (index != 0))
                    {
                        y = y + 150; // 3 images per rows, first image will be at (20,150)
                        x = 0;
                    }
                    picture[index].Location = new Point(x * 210 + 20, y);
                    picture[index].Size = new Size(200, 150);
                    x++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to explain your answer for getting proper attention. SO doesn't believes in code snippet as answers.