# Converting text from textbox to images in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

### What I already have:

I'm writing a program for my hobby geocaching.
The program has to **translate a flag alphabet to text** and the other way around.

What I already have is the following:

- When clicking on different flag images, the alphabetical result turns up in a textbox.

So far ... so good. I will also provide you with the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Vlaggenalfabet
{
    public partial class SeinvlaggenForm : Form
    {


    public SeinvlaggenForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtResultaat.Text = "";
    }


    private void ButtonAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button knop = (Button)sender;
        txtResultaat.Text += " " + knop.Tag + " ";
    }


    private void btnWis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtResultaat.Text = "";
    }
```

So ... what did I do with the flag images? Those are represented as buttons in the application and every button has a tag (alphabet).

**An image can be seen through this link:**
http://i1304.photobucket.com/albums/s537/AngelEyesRH/PriveGeoForum/VlaggenAlfabet_zps14a5f975.jpg

### And now my problem/question:

But now I also want that when there's text written in the textbox, the content would convert to the flag images in a picturebox or something, under the 2 buttons under the textbox.

I really don't know how to manage that. Can somebody provide me with some help please?

### **Edit:**

I've found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868757/displaying-an-array-of-images-in-picturebox).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying a **dictionary** with the images as keys and the corresponding letter as the value or vice versa. That way when text is supplied you can search for the image for each letter in the string

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will look into this and try do make it work. If it won't work I'll be back. ;-)