# Drawing 2 bitmaps in one picturebox

Tags: c#

I have an object and a custom method to draw it, which returns a Bitmap.

I draw one object like so:

```
pictureBox1.Image = MyObject.DrawMyObject(startingPoint);
```

How would I put 2 of them in one picturebox? I tried using some operators, but it seems they are not working for a Bitmap type. I read `Image` property accepts only a single Bitmap, but don't understand how to draw a Bitmap, a then a second one without losing the first.

Comment: By "put 2 pictures on one picturebox", do you mean that you would have 2 pictures displayed next to each other? Create a new image with the correct dimensions, acquire a `Graphics` object and use the `DrawImage()` function two times to draw both pictures in, if that's what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying an array of images in picturebox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868757/displaying-an-array-of-images-in-picturebox). Although the question is talking about an array o images the solution is still valid. Either draw your image into one final image to be displayed or have multiple boxes.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt no, I mean, if I would draw an object, I want to draw a second object next to it on the same pb.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. The way I see it, the `MyObject.DrawMyObject(startingPoint)` gives you an `Image` object, which you display in the `pictureBox1`. So, if you had two objects, `MyObject1` and `MyObject2`, you call the `DrawMyObject()` function on them, and you receive two images. Now you want **both** these pictures displayed **on the same picture box**, the only way to make that happen is to merge the two pictures into one. Or is it, that you want the second picture to be drawn **over** the first picture? Then have some transparency in the pictures and draw over them.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt that's it, I dont quite understand how to merge them into single picture. Not drawing one over the other, I just want to draw 2 objects next to each other on single pb, and for that I guess I need to merge it, but still don't understand how.

Comment: Maybe just using `BackgroundImage` and another `Image` is good enough?

Answer (score 3):

Alright, following up from the comments, you want to merge two pictures, which are hopefully transparent, otherwise you'll just overdraw everything. 
Let image 1 be

[image: a]

And image 2 be

[image: aa]

Notice that they do have the same dimensions (800 x 600), so I don't need to worry about calculating the size. (Otherwise, take the maximum of each pictures width and height as the new dimensions). Since both are transparent, I want to draw the stackoverflow logo over the dices, which I do with `Graphics` object and the `DrawImage` function.

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace stuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Bitmap pImage1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\PNGtest.png");
            Bitmap pImage2 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\logo.png");

            using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pImage1))
            {
                g.DrawImage(pImage2, new Point(0, 0));
                g.Save();
            }

            pImage1.Save(@"C:\Users\...\Desktop\merged.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

Results in
[image]

You can modify the starting point from which the second image will be drawn over the first one with `Point` parameter in `DrawImage()`.

Comment: Oh, the old stackoverflow logo in action =D